# How to make a thread unlock the mutex locked by another thread?

Tags: ruby, mutex

I have several threads and one mutex. A thread can lock this mutex and I want another thread to unlock this mutex, but the following error is thrown:

```
Attempt to unlock a mutex which is locked by another thread
```

How can I ignore this error? Or have another solution?

**Edit**

I have several threads that will do a job. When the first thread start doing the work, it locks the mutex. Others may appear and start doing the same job. After the last thread (provavelemnte, not the first) to finish the job, it must unlock the mutex.

Thus, the first thread locks the mutex, and the last thread unlocks.

Comment: That's how mutex was supposed to work - you can't lock it from one thread and unlock from other.  What is the problem that you were trying to solve by using mutex? May be mutex is not the right choice for you

Answer (score 1):

Realize rescuing of `ThreadError` for block, that unlock `Mutex` like this:

```
begin
    m.unlock
rescue ThreadError => e
    puts "Nothing todo"
end
```

But be carefull: `ThreadError` can be raised as result of other thread-related operations.
And you must be shure that rescuing do not crash program logic.

Comment: or just 're-lock' mutex before unlocking: `mutex.lock; mutex.unlock`

Comment: so... do not relock `Mutex`)) It can be cause of 'deadlock; recursive locking' if you relock it in similar thread.

Answer (score 0):

Mutex is short for *mutual exclusion*. That means that when one thread takes the job and locks its mutex, *other threads are not supposed to touch it*, and are in fact supposed to be blocked until the mutex is released (by the thread that locked it).

Since you seem to want to operate on the job with multiple threads simultaneously, I have no idea what you're trying to do with the mutex. Until you clarify your use case, I can't suggest a proper alternative for you. :-(